# Config paramter default_max_block_cpu_usage and unit tests

Tags: block-producer, unit-tests

We have problem with built-in unit-tests when we increase min_activated_stake (producer_pay.cpp):

```
const int64_t  min_activated_stake   = 300'000'000'0000;
```

And unit tests `agrio_system_tests/multiple_namebids` fail with

> fatal error: in "agrio_system_tests/multiple_namebids": critical check success() == bidname( "alice", "prefb", core_from_string("1.1001") ) has failed [ != billed CPU time (2000 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (1760 us)]

We found that changing value `default_max_block_cpu_usage` (from config.hpp) from 200'000 to 400'000 solve the problem:

```
const static uint32_t   default_max_block_cpu_usage = 200'000; /// max block cpu usage in microseconds
```

1) I want to understand, is this the right way to solve the problem?

2) And how does this parameter affect the operation of the block producers?

3) How can we provide custom `default_max_block_cpu_usage` value for unit-tests and keep original value for production environment ?

Thanks!